# check whether email exist or not in jquery

Tags: email, exists

This is My Code for checking for email exist or not....
The any response does not get by me.
so please provide some solution to me about this problem.There are another file in which check for email in database..but jquery is not giving any response.

And this is my js code..

```
<html>
<head>
 <?php include("head.inc.php");?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //VALIDATE USER EMAIL
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#eml').blur(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST"
                url:check.php,
                data:"username="+$('#eml').val(),
                beforeSend:function(data)
                {   
                    $('#msg').html('chkng..').css("color","green"); 
                },
                success:function(data){

                        if(data =='false')
                        {
                            $('#msg').html("already exist").css("color","red");
                        }
                        else if(data=='true')
                        {
                            $('#msg').html("Valid 6e").css("color","green");
                        }

                }


            });
    });
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm" action="check.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" id="eml"/>
<input type="submit" id="ok" name="ok" value="OK"/>
<div id="msg" class=""></div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

check.php

```
<?php
        include('conf.inc.php');
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $q="select u_fname from users where u_email='$email'";
        $rs=mysql_query($q) or die("query");
        if(mysql_num_rows($rs)==0)
        {
            echo 'true'; //allow to register.
        }
        else   
        {
            echo 'false'; //not allow to register.
        }
?>
```

but i can't get the proper ouptput.
any response hasn't come.

Answer (score 0):

Try using return instead of echo.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($rs)==0)
        {
            return true; //allow to register.
        }
        else   
        {
            return false; //not allow to register.
        }
```

and in js

```
success:function(data){

                        if(data === false)
                        {
                            $('#msg').html("already exist").css("color","red");
                        }
                        else if(data === true)
                        {
                            $('#msg').html("Valid 6e").css("color","green");
                        }
}
```

why === instead of == read here 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Hope it helps!